# Items not rendering into HTML

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC 4 project with one index page that is getting loaded on F5:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Interaction Simulator</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app>
        <div ng-controller="indexController">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in simulations">
                    {{item.name}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I used Nuget to get AngularJS, then added src="~/Scripts/angular.js" to the index page. Then I added a new .js file in the scripts folder:

```
hello-angular.js:
var indexController = function($scope) {
    $scope.simulations = [
        { simName: "TestSim1" },
        { simName: "TestSim2" }];
}
```

When I run this the list of simulations if not rendered, and there are no errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your browser hit the JavaScript lines?

Comment: Do you have an Angular application defined? I'm not sure from your example on how `hello-angular.js` is being called. Take a look through the [`angular-seed`](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) project where there is an explicit `ng-app` attribute plus an `app.js` that matches the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to display `{{item.name}}` but you've defined array of objects with `simName` property.

You should use `{{item.simName}}`

Here it works: http://jsfiddle.net/aartek/6935R/

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Also I needed to add <script src="~/Scripts/hello-angular.js"></script> to Index.cshtml. Thank you.

Comment: I am surprised there was no errors or warnings that tipped me off to this in either Visual Studio or the Chrome debugger.

Comment: There are some Chrome extensions which helps to debug AngularJS and maybe they give some warnings, but i haven't tried them.